# Rapideye 3A Dark Object Subtraction in QGIS?

Tags: qgis-plugins

Is there a method to do Dark Object Subtraction (DOS) with the Semi automatic classification plug-in of QGIS on Rapideye 3A imagery?

Answer (score 1):

No, SCP can only perform DOS for Sentinel2 and Landsat 7/8 as of now.